# How to get all mailbox details using "Get-MailBox" cmdlet?

Tags: exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010, powershell-remoting

I am not able to get all mailboxes using this cmdlet "Get-Mailbox", instead it is returning only one mailbox details for the account which is used for authentication. 
I have enabled windows authentication on Powershell  in IIS for accessing exchange powershell using C# console application and authenticating it with administrator account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are indeed typing "Get-Mailbox" and nothing else either:
A) You do not have the correct access rights to Exchange 
or 
B) You only have one mailbox in Exchange.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. There are multiple mailboxes for sure. What kind of access rights it needs to get the whole data?

Comment: There are several permissions out there, or Role Groups, in which you must be a member.  Usually these are (or should be) managed via security group membership in Active Directory. The role group you might need is "Recipient Management". "Organization Management" is the highest tier of access.

Comment: I have checked permissions/Roles for that user using this cmdlet "Get-ManagementRoleAssignment"  and it is having Organization Management   on most of the functionalities. On Mailbox Import Export and Mailbox Search that user have organization Management role.

Comment: You can verify this membership using - Get-RoleGroupMember "Recipient Management", etc., and check to see if your user is in that role. The role itself has assignments, which is what you were looking at. 

Users are members of Roles, which have certain Role Assignments

Comment: I have executed this cmdlet on exchange powershell but there is not output not even error.

Comment: Ah yes, you may not even be able to run this if you do not have the correct permissions. It's likely you'll need to get with whoever is in the Organization Management group and request these permissions. Likely your Exchange team or AD Wintel

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. It is working now. The user must have Role - 'Organization Management' on Recipient Type - 'UserMailBox'. Then only it will have access of all mailboxes.